# Positioning the notification bar in primefaces

Tags: primefaces

I am new to primefaces and trying to implement the notification bar, it seems that there are only two default potions of the notification bar: top or bottom left of the page. Any idea how I can change this to display the bar at a custom  location, say somewhere below the button?

Refered the bolow showcase example:
http://www.primefaces.org:8080/showcase/ui/panel/notificationBar.xhtml

And here is my code:

```
<p:notificationBar effect="fade" style="color:blue;font-size:12px;width:200px;height:30px;background-color:transparent" widgetVar="bar" >
    <h:outputText value="Notifications" style="font-size:12px;background-color:transparent" />
</p:notificationBar>
```

Comment: Use an overlay panel then…

Answer (score 0):

You can position it using css. It works great afaics. At least so it seems from a little testing in the showcase). Adding

```
#j_idt88.ui-notificationbar.ui-widget {
    top: 315px !important;
    width: 350px;
    left: 330px;
    position: absolute;
}
```

there made it show up beneath the button. `top` needs important since I was not able to get it to be applied using other css specificity rules.

As you can see, this is all very basic css.. Learn that and you'll be happy on a lot more occasions in the future.

But still, why not use an overlay panel?